# Structured data testing tool complains about image url (INVALID_URL)

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

I set the url for the image and I can see image by typing url in the browser, but structured testing tool complains about it. It should be mentioned that I am on development server with `http` protocol and without ssl certificate.

image url: `http://s.my-site.local/u/2020/07/logo.png`

How can I solve this error?

**Update:**

Here is the `json-ld` that I used:

```
{
  "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org\/",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "@id": "http:\/\/my-site.local#Organization",
  "logo": "http:\/\/s.my-site.local\/u\/2020\/07\/logo.png",
  "identifier": "http:\/\/my-site.local#Organization",
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some description",
  "url": "http:\/\/my-site.local"
}
```

Comment: we'd need a bit more context. Can you share the structured data you are using?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I added `json-ld` data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Structured Data Testing Tool chokes on `.local` domains, because it expects the URLs in your structured data to be publicly accessible.

A workaround would be to change your `.local` domain to a `.com` specifically for the structured data test, so that Google doesn't see it as invalid. Google doesn't actually try to visit the URLs when it validates the structured data, so just replacing the TLD should be good enough.